# How to join tables to see dates with null values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: Calendar, Employees, Task.
Employees usually complete their tasks during the week and they don't work during the weekend. What I want to accomplish, is join the tables so I will see every day in a year even if no employee completed any task.

Here is an sql that works for me:

```
SELECT c.date, t.task, e.name
FROM calendar c
  LEFT JOIN tasks t ON (c.date = t.date)
  INNER JOIN employees e ON (t.emp_id = e.id)
WHERE c.date >= "2016-01-01" AND c.date <= "2016-01-07";
```

A result looks like this:

```
Date         Task       Name
...
2016-01-05   Driving    John
2016-01-05   Cooking    Rob
2016-01-06   Installing Jane
2016-01-07   null       null
```

My problem is, that when I add an employees into `WHERE` clause (`WHERE e.name in("John", "Rob", "Jane")`), the last row (`2016-01-07   null       null`) disappears.

What should I change to keep even the dates without employees and tasks in the result? I need these dates to keep in for the final report.

Comment: Why that odd date? (`... AND c.date <= "20016-01-07"`)

Comment: I don't believe that this query can return the result indicated above.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I fixed the typo in the year in date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer here is right. Turn the inner join into a left join to return days without an employee then

```
WHERE c.date between "2016-01-01" and "2016-01-07"
AND (e.name in("John", "Rob", "Jane") or e.name is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner join on employees to a left join, and put the name filter in the join clause, not the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could modify the left join to contain the filter for the query. That means, this works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to fix that date;

```
SELECT c.DATE
    ,t.task
    ,e.NAME
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON (c.DATE = t.DATE)
LEFT JOIN employees e ON t.emp_id = e.id
    AND e.NAME IN ('John' ,'Rob','Jane')
WHERE c.DATE >= "2016-01-01"
    AND c.DATE <= "2016-01-07";
```